# Create a tutorial for my app

Tags: java, android

I want to create a tutorial for my app that will show the user how to use it. For example when you first run an android device it teaches you how to use the system.

[image]

I want my tutorial to just tell the user to swipe the screen to the left and then click on a button.

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create the semi-transparent grey tutorial overlay in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18476088/how-do-i-create-the-semi-transparent-grey-tutorial-overlay-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [ShowcaseView library](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView) on Github. I guess that'll fit your needs.

Comment: yea i know about this,but i couldn't manage with it.any tutorials about it or another way?