# Screen-Over layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I do an android layout that covers with transparent colors the background activity where I can add buttons and texts?

For example

[image: example]
[image: 2]

Comment: DO you have any code to share at all?  Otherwise this is probably a candidate for hold/closure...  Also as a general UI question - whats the point of the second image?  I don't understand what the user is supposed to do there.

Comment: see this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18476088/how-do-i-create-the-semi-transparent-grey-tutorial-overlay-in-android

Comment: Just create a realative layout as the root layout. Put your activity views first and then the other layout with the transparent as second, both match_parent. You can hide the second layout and display when you need it.

Comment: The images represents two help dialogs. I don't know where to start to create an interface as those. What tecnic to use (dialog, activity...)