# How to build a android apps like This

Tags: java, android, animated, instructions

Now i am facing a problem with my apps. 
I want to make a animated hand on my app that help user in this way how to use it.
I give blew a picture sample. Please help. https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgAMU.png

Comment: Please take a look [How to ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I am sure you have to make your animation...to animate your app...and I have seen these type of animation in hybrid application..you can try that...but in android you have to go your ways to do that..

Comment: Thank you. I find my solution on following link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18476088/how-do-i-create-the-semi-transparent-grey-tutorial-overlay-in-android

Answer (score 0):

The image you provided is how Google shows off and demonstrates their new features.

Google has created the "Blue hand overlay" and the other effects you see in the picture.

You will need to create your own image as im sure Google has some sort of copyright on every thing you see.

After you have your own "guiding hand" image **you will apply the image to the screen with a transparent background and a "ok" button** in order to mimic what you see in the picture.